# Jquery progresbar in php table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to make a table which gets data from `mysql` and show the rating value in a mySQL table as a `jquery` animated progressbar. I got the table but I don't know how to make that progress bar work in the loop.
It might not be the best way to go about this.

I want to display the retrieved data as a bar graph.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#progressbar").height(10).progressbar({
                    value : 1
                });
                $("#progressbar > .ui-progressbar-value").animate({
                    width : "50%"
                }, 1000);
            });

        </script>

        <title>Random page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        $test = 3;

        echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>CPU</th>
<th>Speed</th>
<th>Cores</th>
<th>TDP</th>
<th>Preformace</th>
<th>Overclocking</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>";

        while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($datas)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['CPU'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['Speed'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['Cores'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['TDP'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['Preformace'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['Overclocing'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $record['Price'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Comment: there's a lot of progressbar on the internet, if you want to create your own, you will need, php to know how many kbs have been upload, CSS to display the progressbar and jquery to make it dynamic (this is the theory)

Comment: Are you wanting the progress bar to show up while you're waiting for the data to be loaded from the table, or do you want to display the retrieved data as a bar graph?

Comment: I want to display the retrieved data as a bar graph.